# Using thousands of Tasks with a timeout efficiently

Tags: c#, sockets, parallel-processing, task

I am implementing a Library L that communicates via Sockets with another application A.

Basic workflow is as followed:

1. L connects to A.
2. L sends ~50.000 pieces of information I to A, and
   creates a task T for every I that is sent out.
3. L listens for incoming results from A, and once reuslts are there, uses a
   TaskCompletionSource to set the results of the Tasks T
4. L creates a Task T2 with a set Timeout (Task.WhenAny(T,Task.Delay(xx))
5. L uses Task.WhenAll(T2) to wait for timeout or results on all sent information.

Managing the underlying data structure is no problem at all. The main problem is that assembling the "main" Task.WhenAll(T2) costs around 5-6 seconds on my computer with ca. 50.000 entries (creating 50.000*2+1 tasks).

I can't think off a more lightweight way that accomplishes the same, however. It should use all Cores available and be non-blocking, and support timeouts aswell.

Is there a way to accomplish the same using the Parallel- or ThreadPool classes which enhances the performance?

EDIT:
Code showing how the basic setup is:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/gIq2DP

Comment: So it takes about 100 microseconds to make a task? How much work do you plan to give each task? It better be significantly larger that 100uS or setup overhead will swamp any parallelism you hope to achieve.  Out of curiosity, when you manufacture 50,000*2 tasks, how much does your VM image grow?  If you manufacture 50,000 tasks and give each the empty procedure to run, how long does it take to run?  On a 1 core system?  on a 4 or 8 core system?

Comment: OK, post some code. I once benchmarked task creation throughput. It was like 10m per second on my machine. The costs are in *your* code, not in the TPL.

Comment: I would be even better if you posted a screenshot of a CPU profiler result.

Comment: The main "task" of the task is to wait for other application to return the results. I use Tasks as a way of simplifying the parallel programming. Currently running on 4 core i7 4770k @ 4.3 GHz using 16 GB RAM.
When testing with 20.000 Tasks, overall memory consumption peaked at 50 MB.
EDIT:
I benchmarked the code before. The creation of the Tasks itself takes around 14% of all the CPU cycles used, and I'd like to cut these down.

Comment: Clearly all those tasks can't actually be running simultaneously, since they would consume 1MB of stack each - i.e  it would take 20GB.

Comment: Your benchmark is invalid. `Task.WhenAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(_ => new TaskCompletionSource<object>().Task)) + ""` shows 3m such tasks per second in LINQPad. Post code.

Comment: Alright, while assembling the minimal working example I found the underlying bug. When creating the Task.WhenAny(originalTask,TaskDelay), I actually  did an await on them, causing all tasks to wait twice, creating the overhead. Following example demonstrates how it is working now:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/gIq2DP . Cut the time with 80.000 tasks from 8 seconds to 0.5 seconds - thanks everyone

Comment: @Zahlii: Please provide code to me... only then can I make my answer more precise.

Comment: @displayName added it. Running performance tests now with the new code base.

Comment: OK, with that code 80000 tasks take 500ms. Is that the same performance you are getting? I tested with LINQPad.

Comment: @usr nope, as I stated earlier in a commetn I fixed a bug with the tasks I found while trying to assemble above minimal example - I cam currently looking whether the bug fixed the performance. I used to take about 5-10seconds for 80.000 tasks before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start a total of *n* `LongRunningTasks`, where *n* is the number of cores on your machine. Each task should run on one core. It would be a waste to create 50K new tasks for every I that you want to send. Instead design the tasks to accept *I and the socket information - where this information is to be sent*.

Create a `BlockingCollection<Tuple<I, SocketInfo>>`. Start one task to populate this blocking collection. The other n long running tasks that you created earlier can keep taking tuples of information and the address to send the information and then perform the job for you in a loop that will break when blocking collection is done.

Timeouts can be set in the long running tasks itself.

This entire setup will keep your CPU busy to the maximum with *useful work* rather than keeping it needlessly busy with a "job" of *50K tasks' creation*.

Since the operations (like this network operation) which happen beyond the main memory are [very very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236796/fastest-way-to-copy-files-from-one-directory-to-another/32236951#32236951) for the CPU, feel free to set *n* not just equal to number of cores in your machine but even thrice that value. In my code demonstration I have set it equal to the number of cores only.

With the code at the provided link, this is one way...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestConsoleApplication
{
    public static class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            TaskRunningTest();
        }

        private static void TaskRunningTest()
        {
            var s = new Stopwatch();
            const int totalInformationChunks = 50000;
            var baseProcessorTaskArray = new Task[Environment.ProcessorCount];
            var taskFactory = new TaskFactory(TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskContinuationOptions.None);
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();

            var itemsToProcess = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<Information, Address>>(totalInformationChunks);

            s.Start();
            //Start a new task to populate the "itemsToProcess"
            taskFactory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                // Add Tuples of Information and Address to which this information is to be sent to.
                Console.WriteLine("Done intializing all the jobs...");
                // Finally signal that you are done by saying..
                itemsToProcess.CompleteAdding();
            });

            //Initializing the base tasks
            for (var index = 0; index < baseProcessorTaskArray.Length; index++)
            {
                var thisIndex = index;
                baseProcessorTaskArray[index] = taskFactory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (!itemsToProcess.IsAddingCompleted && itemsToProcess.Count != 0)
                    {
                        Tuple<Information, Address> item;
                        itemsToProcess.TryTake(out item);
                        //Process the item
                        tcs.TrySetResult(thisIndex);
                    }
                });
            }

            // Need to provide new timeout logic now
            // Depending upon what you are trying to achieve with timeout, you can devise out the way

            // Wait for the base tasks to completely empty OR
            // timeout and then stop the stopwatch.
            Task.WaitAll(baseProcessorTaskArray); 
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(s.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }

        private class Address
        {
            //This class should have the socket information
        }

        private class Information
        {
            //This class will have the Information to send
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Profiling shows that most time (90%?) is spent in timer setup, expiration and disposal. This seems plausible to me.

Maybe you can create your own super cheap timeout mechanism. Enqueue timeouts into a priority queue ordered by expiration time. Then, run a single timer every 100ms and make that timer expire everything in the priority queue that is due.

The cost of doing this would be one `TaskCompletionSource` per timeout and some small further processing.

You can even cancel timeouts by removing them from the queue and just dropping the `TaskCompletionSource`.