# Fastest way to create and move backup files to a directory?

Tags: c#

I want to create a backup file before performing any operation on the file and then move it a to a location with the folder structure being
`D:\BACKUP\(Date)\(Time)`.

What is the fastest way of doing it? I'm currently doing it as below

```
string path = textBox1.Text;
var files = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "dtpo", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                     .SelectMany(t => Directory.GetFiles(t, "*.txt")).ToArray();

foreach (var file in files)
{
    File.Copy(file,file+".bk",true);
    string OnlyDate=DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    string OnlyTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
    if (!Directory.Exists(@"D:\BACKUP\" + OnlyDate+"\\"+OnlyTime))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"D:\BACKUP\" + OnlyDate+"\\"+OnlyTime);
    }

    string rootFolderPath = Path.GetFullPath(file+".bk");
    string targetPath=@"D:\BACKUP\" + OnlyDate+"\\"+OnlyTime+"\\"+Path.GetFileName(file+".bk");
    File.Move(rootFolderPath, targetPath);
    //Do the processes
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest way to copy files from one directory to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32236796/fastest-way-to-copy-files-from-one-directory-to-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directory.exists can be  bypassed, createdirectory won't run if it does.   Also recommend you don't do 2 io operations to write the file.   Just write directly to the output using file.copy.

Comment: Can you explain a little? what do you mean by `Just write directly to the output using file.copy.`

Comment: The bk file isn't needed... Call system.io.file.copy(file,Target path)

Comment: Are you talking about removing the line `File.Copy(file,file+".bk",true);` ?

Comment: Yes...that's unnecessary...as is the directory exists check

Comment: Thanks for helping :)